# SPFX - How to deploy more views to a list in a SPFX project?

Tags: list, listview, sharepoint, spfx

I have a SPFX webpart project that deploys a custom list with a default view.
Until here, everything works fine.

What I need is to deploy more views besides this default view, but not matter what I try (even copying the definition - and changing the BaseViewID), the list breaks.

Does anybody know how to deploy more views on a SPFX project?

The default view:

```
<View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="Todos os itens" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="FALSE" MobileDefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
  <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
  <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
  <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
  <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Field1"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Field2"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Field3"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Editor"/>
  </ViewFields>
  <Query>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name="Field1" />
    </OrderBy>
  </Query>
</View>
```

The error when trying to access a new view:

[image]

Something goes wrong.
Cannot complete this action. Please try again

The error when trying to access the list configuration:
[image]

List doesn't exist.

Comment: This seems to be a "classic view" - is JSLInk really supported in modern lists? I deployed views programmatically using PNPJS.